# Javascript heap error when nativescript application bundled with webpack

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Javascript heap error coming up when nativescript application is bundled with webpack.

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

this is the error I am getting when its run using

`tns run android --bundle --env.aot --env.uglify`

```
nativescript version 5.2.2
@angular/core: "~7.2.0
nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.20.3
@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0
```

Detailed log

<--- Last few GCs --->

> [31199:0x24e6180]    38234 ms: Mark-sweep 1367.2 (1453.5) -> 1363.6
>   (1458.5) MB, 912.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.116, current mu = 0.044)
>   allocation failure scavenge might not succeed [31199:0x24e6180]
>   39132 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.4 (1458.5) -> 1368.5 (1458.5) MB, 844.5 /
>   0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.087, current mu = 0.060) allocation failure GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

```
0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2d645c5dbe1d]
Security context: 0x10886211e6e1 <JSObject>
1: bindWorker(aka bindWorker) [0x39b993a31201] 
[/home/user/jishnu/projects/oes-dt- 
mobile/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:~28311] [pc=0x2d645d75c74d] 
(this=0x005cd5b026f1 <undefined>,node=0x06f6ec3100a1 <NodeObject map = 
0xe7113ce3aa1>)
2: bind(aka bind) [0x39b993a31101] [/home/user/jishnu/projects/oes-dt- 
mobile/node_modules/typescript/lib/ty...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8daaa0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8daaec  [node]
 3: 0xad73ce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xad7604 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xec4c32  [node]
 6: 0xec4d38 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xed0e12 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xed1744 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xed43b1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xe9c695  [node]
11: 0xea1354 v8::internal::Factory::NewByteArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: 0xe2a88a v8::internal::TranslationBuffer::CreateByteArray(v8::internal::Factory*) [node]
13: 0xc41edf v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::GenerateDeoptimizationData() [node]
14: 0xc42672 v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::FinalizeCode() [node]
15: 0xd5167b v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::FinalizeCode() [node]
16: 0xd51a8d v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::FinalizeJobImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
17: 0xc1562d v8::internal::Compiler::FinalizeCompilationJob(v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
18: 0xc0bbbb v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::InstallOptimizedFunctions() [node]
19: 0xe720bb v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node]
20: 0x113ced5 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
21: 0x2d645c5dbe1d
```

Error is not there with command `tns run` without --bundle. The error came after adding some workers for some app optimisations. followed [NativeScript Worker Loader and NativeScriptWorkerPlugin](https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader) for adding workers with webpack bundling.

Comment: I came across similar issue today. Upon looking up, the solution that many people suggested is to update node heap size to 4096 (for larger projects). (I could not figure out server file used by storybook)

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in your terminal window:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`

then run the `tns run ...` command, it should fix the issue.

If you add the `export ...` to your ~/.bashrc (or similar), you won't have to run it manually every time you start a new terminal.